# the difference between independent random variables and independent events, a strange instance

Tags: probability, random-variables

I know the conclusion that if event $A$ and $B$ are independent, $P(AB)=P(A)P(B) $. And furthermore, the two sigma algebra $\sigma(I_A)$ and $\sigma(I_B)$ should be independent, where $I_A:\Omega \rightarrow R ,I_A(\omega) := 1 \space if \space \omega \in A \space or \space 0 \space otherwise.$ 
And here is my strange example, suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two independent Bernoulli random variables, let $Z:=(Y-X)^2$, we can prove that any two of them are independent, but three of them are not using sigma algebra I've mentioned before. But suppose we consider this problem as 2 independent events(since we know Bernoulli r.v. just have 2 values, $0$ and $1$), so I set $P(X=1)=a, P(X=0)=1-a, P(Y=1)=b, P(Y=0)=1-b$ and than I have $P(Z=0)=ab+(1-a)(1-b), P(Z=1)=a(1-b)+b(1-a)$. And then I want to prove $P(X=1;Z=1)= P(X=1)P(Z=1)$, $P(X=1;Z=1) = a(1-b) \ne a(a(1-b)+ b(1-a)), for \space all \space a,b\in R.$ But if X, Z are independent, the above equation should hold. Where have I made a mistake, is P(Z) I calculated wrong or there are some concepts I've not been very clear. Help me! Thanks! And I suppose you have the basic knowledge of Probability Theory so if you have some questions about the notation above, please just search on the Wikipedia.

Comment: What definition of independence are you using for sigma algebra?

Comment: 2 sigma algebras$A_1,A_2$ are independent, if for any $a_1 \in A_1, a_2 \in A_2$  we have $P(a_1 \cap a_2) = P(a_1)P(a_2)$

Comment: Right, and as you have just shown that *there exists* $a_1\in \sigma(X), a_2\in \sigma(Z)$ where $P(a_1\cap a_2)\neq P(a_1)P(a_2)$, therefore...

Answer (score 1):

The sample set is $\Omega=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$ and we have the sigma algebrae:

$\sigma(X)=\{\emptyset,\{(0,0),(0,1)\},\{(1,0),(1,1)\},\Omega\}$

$\sigma(Z)=\{\emptyset,\{(0,0),(1,1)\},\{(0,1),(1,0)\},\Omega\}$

These algebrae will be independent if for *every* finite set of intersections of elements of the algebra, the independence rule holds for their measures.  But as you have shown, a counterexample exists.$$\begin{align}\mathsf P\{(1,0),(1,1)\}\cap\{(0,1),(1,0)\}&=\mathsf P\{(1,0)\}\\&=a(1-b)\\\mathsf P\{(1,0),(1,1)\}\cdot\mathsf P\{(0,1),(1,0)\}&=a\cdot((1-a)b+a(1-b))\\&=a(a+b-2ab)\end{align}$$

This is not a strange counterexample, it is just a counterexample.

Therefore these sigma algebrae are not independent for arbitrary values of $a,b$.

Comment: in my opinion, the Bernoulli random variable $X$ can also be written as $I_X$ (I consider it as a random variable of whether a certain event happens or not ),  and I think $I_X$ and $I_Y$ are independent iff.  the events of X and Y are independent. So if the events of X are not independent of those in Y, the two Bernoulli random variables are not independent. Is there something wrong with my deduction?

Comment: Not quite. It is not sensible to indicate whether a *random variable* happens or not.  Random variables don't *happen*, rather they *realise values*.  So when $X$ *is* a random variable, and *not* an event, then $I_X$ is not sensible as a random variable, although $I_{X=1}$ is. (But, yes, $X=I_{X=1}$ *when* $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider that a can only take values 0 or 1:

When a=0 your expression evaluates to 0, as expected.

When a=1 it evaluates to a(1-b) as expected.

Your result was correct it just needed another step to see the equivalence.

Comment: $a$ is not so limited.  $a$, being the probability that $X=1$, may be a value in the interval $[0;1]$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Do we not have $I_A(\omega) \in \{0,1\}$ given in the second line of the question? Or is that not related to the rest of the question in the way I thought it was?

Comment: $I_A(\omega)$ is not the probability function but a random variable

Comment: @ALEX I see. What's best practice for this site - leave the wrong answer here or just delete it?

Comment: Here $I_A$ and $I_B$ are the Bernoulli random variables, $X$ and $Z$.